# Add Data to GridView from Multiple Tables ASP.NET in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I need to know how to bind grid view with 2 tables, I already bind it with PostedVoucher table but I need to add column trans_name from transactions table how can I do that ???

html code :

```
                <asp:Label ID="debit" runat="server" Text='<%# (Eval("stat_flag").ToString() =="d" ) ? Eval("stat_amount"): "0" %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>

              <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="دائن">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="credit" runat="server" Text='<%# (Eval("stat_flag").ToString() =="c" ) ? Eval("stat_amount"): "0" %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
                                <asp:BoundField  DataField="stat_desc" 
                                HeaderText="البيان" ItemStyle-Font-Size="Small"/>

                            <asp:BoundField  DataField="serial" 
                             HeaderText=" رقم السند " ItemStyle-Font-Size="Small"/>

                              <asp:BoundField  DataField="stat_date" dataformatstring="{0:dd/MM/yyyy}"
                                HeaderText="التاريخ" ItemStyle-Font-Size="Small"/>
```

C# code :

```
   SqlParameter[] para = new SqlParameter[4];
   para[0] = new SqlParameter("@stat_sub_leger", ddlACCcode.SelectedValue);
    para[1] = new SqlParameter("@branch", DDLBranch.SelectedValue);
    para[2] = new SqlParameter("@from", db.getDate(txtFrom.Text));
    para[3] = new SqlParameter("@to", db.getDate(txtTo.Text));

    DataTable dtreport = db.SelectCmdText("Select * from PostedVoucher where stat_sub_leger = @stat_sub_leger 
             and branch=@branch and stat_date between @from and @to ORDER BY stat_date ", para);


    GridView1.DataSource = dtreport;
    GridView1.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@FEBY  you can write query to get combined value from your  both table and then bind it to your grid